# Devtools in Edge does not work after recent updates

Tags: microsoft-edge, developer-tools

Does anyone have a solution for a case, when DevTools in Edge is blank, and not showing anything?
It became broken after some of the recent Windows releases/updates.

Answer (score 3):

In Microsoft Edge 93 and above, you may need to go to Settings and enable F12 shortcut to enable developer tool, see screenshot below.

[image: Microsoft Edge Developer Tool]

Comment: What a weird way to name the option that enables the Dev Tools. Your solution works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to the following steps to Repair Edge browser.

1. Open Start > Settings > Apps > Apps & features.
2. Scroll down to Microsoft Edge, Click it.
3. Click the Advanced options.
4. Click Repair.
5. Restart Edge browser.

If repair does not work, try performing a Reset.

If they all not work, try to [reinstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/reinstall-microsoft-edge/15374c1e-f5c5-44e7-9378-cd33e48e8395)

Still not working? Try performing a repair upgrade:

[http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki...](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085)

Comment: So far, nothing helped, and EDGE became even much more broken: it lags a lot, unable to open sites, tabs hang and refuse to close. The link to reinstall is outdated, probably: the command is broken, throws errors.  I'll try other manuals for Edge reinstall.

Comment: Have you re-installed the Edge browser success? If not, you could download the Microsoft edge from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) (This is the new Microsoft Edge, perhaps you need to [update the Windows](http://www.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/default.aspx)).

Comment: Wow, that finally worked! Edge now runs okay, and so does its Devtools! Could be an accepted answer! Thanks.